# Cast function doesn't work in Update query - getting arithmetic overflow error

Tags: sql-server, sql-update, sqldatatypes

I'm running into to a issue where I'm getting a arithmetic over flow error :

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 8, Line 10
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric.

I run the select query below and it works fine. I am trying to update the `Coitem_mst` table. I'm using the query shown below to update.

The problem is the datatype for the column I'm updating is `DECIMAL(11,5)`. I'm not sure how to squeeze the results so I can do the insert.

Sample values

- Uf_UnitWeight = 24.60000, 28.32000, 14.76000
- qty_ordered = 900.00000000, 100.00000000, 50.00000000

Code:

```
SELECT
    CAST((CAST(Uf_UnitWeight AS DECIMAL(11,5)) * 
       CAST(qty_ordered AS DECIMAL(19, 8))) AS DECIMAL(31, 13)) AS extweight 
FROM
    coitem_mst

UPDATE coitem_mst
SET Uf_ExtWeight = CAST((CAST(unit_weight AS DECIMAL(11, 5)) * 
                           CAST(qty_ordered AS DECIMAL(19, 8))) AS DECIMAL(31, 13))
WHERE Uf_ExtWeight IS NULL
```

Comment: why not an additional Cast to the final, column precision/scale?  (if you're ok with any loss of precision)

Comment: that is -   clearly numeric(31,13) <> numeric(11,5) .......   so why not (11,5) ?

Comment: i get the same error when I try (11,5)

Comment: what do you get for *** SELECT max(1.0 * Uf_UnitWeight * qty_ordered) as HighestVal *** ?  Is it too big?  If the value is ever greater than 999,999.0 then I guess it won't fit in the field.

Comment: I reckon you need a bigger Uf_ExtWeight  field

Comment: I get 2369198.000000000, I’m afraid I would need to recreate the table.